# Whats the difference between high pass filter and cutting in EQ (filter curve) in Audacity?

Tags: audacity

For example i want to set a `High pass filer` with 100Hz with roll off by 6db. If in my `Filter curve` i start to roll off by 6db from 100Hz to below.

Is there any technical difference between these two acts or i am doing the same thing just in different way?

Answer (score 2):

As of Audacity 2.3.0, I found that the High Pass filter changes phase of the audio (but the Equalization filter doesn't). This makes it not suitable for the case of mixing two tracks from the same source. So, for this purpose, I'd still use EQ with a 24 dB per octave slope to simulate a high-pass filter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know correct answer, but you can easily check it your self.

1. Filter audio sample with HP filter
2. Filter the same sample with FC EQ
3. Phase invert one of the samples
4. Sum samples (play them the same time)
   If result is silence - filters do the same thing. If there are some noises - algorithms of cutting not the same.

Comment: Adding a signature with a link to your web site to all your posts is not acceptable. I will submit an edit suggestion to roll back, and flag for moderator attention. See also [How not to be a spammer.](/help/promotion)

Comment: @Jdth - do note that you can add that information to your profile instead.  A link to your profile is automatically added to all your contributions and people are free to click thru to your profile where you can have more about yourself.